# Advanced customization of Minted code?

Tags: color, minted, code

I'm a newbie to LaTeX, especially the `minted` package. I would like to customize it such that the code has a similar style to the attached screenshot. Specifically, I wish to be able to customize:

- The font and background shape / color of `mintinline`
- The spacing between background edge and text inside `minted`
- Round corners of background in `minted`
- The line spacing in `minted`

---

Here's what I have thus far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newverbs}

\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{22,43,58}

\newverbcommand{\cverb}{\color{inline}}{}
\usemintedstyle{paraiso-dark}
\setminted[java]{bgcolor=bg, fontfamily=fdm, fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{java}
    public class ClassName
\end{minted}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Could you extend the code to a full but minimal compilable document, please? People will be more eager to help if they don't need to find a way to make your sample compilable before they can start working on the actual issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. This uses `tcolorbox` to create a box around your listing (the keys `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` allow you to specify the distance between box and text).

For a customization of your `\mintinline` see the examples on `\DeclareTotalTCBox` (page 440 in the tcolorbox manual).

[image: tcblisting]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: 1}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, skins}

\tcbset{listing engine=minted}

\newtcblisting{javalst}{listing only, minted language=java, minted style=paraiso-dark,
    colback=bg, enhanced, frame hidden, minted options={fontfamily=fdm, 
    fontsize=\footnotesize, tabsize=2, breaklines, autogobble}}

\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{22,43,58}
\setminted[java]{bgcolor=bg, fontfamily=fdm, fontsize=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\begin{javalst}
    public class ClassName {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(args);
            }
    }
\end{javalst}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly! With regards to `mintinline`, I tried implementing the `\DeclareTotalTCBox` command, however I still am unable to figure out how to get it to be like in my example. Could you help out with that as well please?

Comment: @RichardRobinson I did not quite get what you want. The example you have shown looks like rendered markdown where inline code is normally not syntax highlighted while minted does so. If you only want to reproduce this you only need to set `colback` (with frame hidden as in my example) and the font color (I do not know the key's name, but it should be easy to find this in the documentation).

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want to do! How do I go about setting `colback` and the font for `mintinline` though?

Comment: @RichardRobinson Use the example provided in the manual. If that doesn't work, please ask a new question showing what exactly did not work for you.

Comment: Ok, I did as such: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452249/how-do-i-set-a-background-color-and-font-for-inline-verb-text

Comment: I removed `fontfamily=fdm`, then the default page wide `\setmonofont{Consolas}` works fine in the box