# How do I set a background color and font for inline verb text?

Tags: color, tcolorbox, verbatim, minted, code

I wish to customize the `verb` command such that I can customize the font and color, as well as set a rounded colored rectangle as background.

I found this in the Tcolorbox manual:

```
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\commandbox}{ s v }
{verbatim,colupper=white,colback=black!75!white,colframe=black}
{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textcolor{red}{\ttfamily\bfseries > }}{}%
\lstinline[language=command.com,keywordstyle=\color{blue!35!white}\bfseries]^#2^}
```

which appears to be similar to what I desire. However, I get numerous errors:

```
- Undefined control sequence
- You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

This is the header code so far with the above included:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, skins}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{2mm}\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=bg, colframe=bg, arc=1.2pt]}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}\vspace{2mm}}%

\usepackage{newverbs}
\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}{\color{inline}}{}
\usemintedstyle{paraiso-dark}

\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{22,43,58}
\setminted{fontfamily=fdm, fontsize=\footnotesize, gobble=4, baselinestretch=1.2}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\commandbox}{ s v }
{verbatim,colupper=white,colback=black!75!white,colframe=black}
{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textcolor{red}{\ttfamily\bfseries > }}{}%
\lstinline[language=command.com,keywordstyle=\color{blue!35!white}\bfseries]^#2^}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\title{\Huge{\textbf{Programming in C, Java, \& More}}}
\author{Richard Robinson, B.Eng. Cand.}

\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use library `xparse`.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: 1}
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings, minted, skins, xparse}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{2mm}\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=bg, colframe=bg, arc=1.2pt]}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{tcolorbox}\vspace{2mm}}%

\usepackage{newverbs}
\definecolor{inline}{RGB}{187,57,82}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}{\color{inline}}{}
\usemintedstyle{paraiso-dark}

\definecolor{bg}{RGB}{22,43,58}
\setminted{fontfamily=fdm, fontsize=\footnotesize, gobble=4, baselinestretch=1.2}

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\commandbox}{ s v }
{verbatim,colupper=red!75!black,colback=lightgray, enhanced, frame hidden, arc=2pt}
{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textcolor{red}{\ttfamily\bfseries > }}{}%
\lstinline[language=command.com,keywordstyle=\color{blue!35!white}\bfseries]^#2^}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\title{\Huge{\textbf{Programming in C, Java, \& More}}}
\author{Richard Robinson, B.Eng. Cand.}

\begin{document} 

\commandbox{ABC}

\end{document}
```